How can I remove playlist recommendations from my YouTube home page? (That's playlists not single videos)
I am regularly offered entire playlists with no option to indicate they don't interest me or to stop recommending this channel (three-dot menu).
For weeks now I have been harassed with a playlist entitled “bronze age collapse” from the “Study of Antiquity and the Middle Ages” Podcast. Hovering over the video does not make the three-dot menu appear.
I would very much like to get rid of this playlist as well as other playlists with no three-dot menu.

As of November 2024 there's no way to do it within Youtube itself. But if you're on a web browser using the Ublock Origin extension, you can hide playlists from your home feed with this filter:
www.youtube.com##ytd-browse[page-subtype="home"] ytd-rich-item-renderer:has(ytd-playlist-thumbnail:not([hidden]))

Go to Ublock Origin > Settings > My filters. And paste that code in a new line.
Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/comments/17zs9wr/

Thank you for your quick response. I have added the filter to the list.
